# Overloading a method in FMX.Platform.iOS

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

within `FMX.Platform.iOS` this method is added to the App delegate

```
class_addMethod(appDelegateClass, sel_getUid('application:didReceiveLocalNotification:'),    
@applicationDidReceiveLocalNotification, 'v@:@@');
```

And its procedure is :

```
procedure applicationDidReceiveLocalNotification(self: id; _cmd: SEL; application: PUIApplication;
notification: Pointer); cdecl;

begin
  PlatformCocoa.FAppDelegate.application(TUIApplication.Wrap(application), TUILocalNotification.Wrap(notification));
end;
```

I want to overload this method in my main unit, but it only works if I remove the declaration of it from `FMX.Platform.iOS`

In my main unit I add the Method as follows:

```
class_addMethod(objc_getClass('DelphiAppDelegate'), sel_getUid('application:didReceiveLocalNotification:'),
@applicationDidReceiveLocalNotification, 'v@:@@');
```

And my procedure:

```
procedure applicationDidReceiveLocalNotification(self: id; _cmd: SEL;
application: PUIApplication; notification: Pointer);
begin
    ShowMessage('it works');
end;
```

I want to try and Keep out of the `FMX.Platform.iOS` source as much as I can, is there a way to tell the compiler to use my applicationDidReceiveLocalNotification and not the one in the source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Embarcadero's method is added using Objective-C's `class_addMethod()`, try using Objective-C's `class_replaceMethod()` function to replace it with your own implementation.  There are tons of online tutorials that explain how to use **method swizzling** in iOS to add/override methods.  Please search around.  You will not find any Delphi examples, though, so you will have to do some translating.

Comment: yesterday I went into the runtime unit to go and look for a "removeMethod" or something similar but I should have instead just gone to the iOS documentation as usual, I added the class_replaceMethod to the Macapi.ObjCRuntime unit and its working perfectly, my only question is, should I submit it as a "enhancement" bug so that it can be available for future versions without adding to the source?