# Delphi - Handle Push Notifications when app is running?

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

This is how we handle them at `XCode`:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
   didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
  NSString *message = nil;
  id alert = [userInfo objectForKey:@"alert"];
  if ([alert isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    message = alert;
  } else if ([alert isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    message = [alert objectForKey:@"body"];
  }
  if (alert) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
                                       message:@"AThe message."  delegate:self
                             cancelButtonTitle:@"button 1"
                             otherButtonTitles:@"button", nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
  }
```

How do we catch Push Notifications if the `iOS` application is already running at the same way but using `Delphi 10 Seattle`?

Comment: You should change the title of your question to include Delphi 10 Seattle. Its currently too misleading

Comment: @SausageMachine done. I'll be leaving it as Delphi so it won't be limited to it's last version.

Comment: @SausageMachine, that's what tags are for.

Comment: @Johan. When you browse by the iOS tag for example, then your will see the list of titles. This question is really too specific and particular to Delphi, people who don't know anything about Delphi will click on the title assuming its about iOS and push. But if you don't know Delphi then you can't answer the question, therefore you clicked on the question and read it and consequently wasted your time as its not till you get to the bottom of the question that it is obvious it is about Delphi. Hence putting that in the title makes it clear from the onset and from the search view.

Comment: @SausageMachine, read the discussions on Meta. The tag is the correct place to narrow down the scope of a question, not the title. The title should just list the question.

Answer (score 0):

*Note*: Sadly I can not test this as I don't have a Mac with me at the moment but this should work

Inside `FMX.Platform.iOS` you will find the

```
ApplicationDidReceiveRemoteNotification
```

Method, so it is implemented in Delphi

```
procedure TApplicationDelegate.applicationDidReceiveRemoteNotification(
  Sender: UIApplication; ANotification: NSDictionary);
begin
  PlatformCocoa.ReceivedRemoteNotification(ANotification);
end;
```

In there you can then get the Notification as a `NSDictionary` and you can then read the values from that `NSDictionary` to handle it in a way that you want

You can also refer to Remy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34023980/overloading-a-method-in-fmx-platform-ios/%22Answer%22) on my one question regarding **method swizzling** telling the App to rather use your version of `ApplicationDidReceiveRemoteNotification` and not the one in the source

Answer (score 0):

iOS only

Drop a `TEMSProvider` component on the form 
Drop a `TPushEvents` component on the form 
Bind the `TPushEvents.Provider` to the `TEMSProvider`

in code somewhere set `TPushEvents.Active := True` or enable it's AutoActivate property

TPushEvents has an event called `PushEvents1PushReceived` handle it